# PHP: How to find position of (user-defined) occurrence of a string using stripos

Tags: php

There is strpos() to find First occurrence, and strrpos() to find last occurrence.

[This](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-strpos.php) tutorial explained that it's possible to get any occurrence using a loop, but that might be not fast when the haystack is big. And my code is looking ugly now.

Is there a way to find 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc occurrence without looping over the haystack? I mean, finding the required occurrence directly without looping? Possible?

Comment: You can not. Even without loop, the function that you call (say `findall()`) uses loop eventually.

Comment: @eyazici I mean, I just want to find just one specific occurrence, let's say 4th occurrence only, do I have to use a loop if I want only the 4th occurrence?

Comment: The program can't know what is contained in the string without visiting every position at least once, so, without an index of some kind, whether it is a loop in your code or a built-in function, it will have to visit every character.  What you want to worry about are **N^2** loops or worse.  The sample in the tutorial is not really that bad because it's skipping ahead on each next iteration of the loop.  It seems like it will close to as efficient as possible.

Comment: @evilReiko How would you know the occurrence that you find is 4th occurrence? Your function or one of the functions that is in your call stack have to use at least one loop to iterate over your haystack.

Comment: @renesis: actually, it only has to look at `(length of haystack)-(length of needle)` characters. There's no point in looking at the last 9 characters for a substring that's 10 characters long, e.g.

Comment: @Marc B What you are saying is only true if it's not in the middle of a match detection.  It will have to look to the very last character if the match is exactly at the end.  Regardless, in terms of measuring performance, that's still **N**, so I don't see what the significance is.

Comment: @renesis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore. If you have a haystack 'abcefghijklm' and needle 'nopq', it is IMPOSSIBLE for the the needle to exist in its entirety from 'k' onwards (3 chars left in haystack, 4 chars in needle), so there is no reason to check at k,l,m.

Comment: @Marc B - From that link: "while still linear in the size of the string being searched" - That's the point I'm getting at.  And I agreed with the scenario you just mentioned.  But replace `jkl` with `nop` and you have to search to the last character.  That's what I just said in my last comment.  So what is the significance of what you are saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, but it will not be faster than looping with strpos.

```
if (preg_match_all("/(match this string)/g",$string,$matches))
{
   echo $matches[0] ; // this is the whole string
   echo $matches[1] ; // first match
   echo $matches[2] ; // second match
   echo $matches[3] ; // and so on
}
```

If you wan to replace those occurrences, use `str_replace()`. That way you don't have to worry about offsets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) with the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag so it'll capture all the matches as well as their position in the source string.

```
preg_match('/your string/', $source, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

$matches will be an array containing the offsets and copies of the matched string

Comment: There is hardly any possible way this will perform better than the tutorial in question.  It certainly looks better though (though you could wrap the other algorithm in a function anyway).

Comment: For this specific question, regular expressions are not quite better than the mentioned `strpos()` or `strstr()` method.